# Need Jmeter Regular Expression Extractor

Tags: jmeter

I need to extract value from the response body text and need to add that value for another request. I need to write a regular expression to capture the below-mentioned value.

```
<id>45893943</id>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a [regular expression](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html) - it would be something like `<id>(\d+)</id>`  where:

- `d` - matches any number
- `+` - repetition

[image]

It might be easier for you to consider [Boundary Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-boundary-extractor-vs-the-regular-expression-extractor-in-jmeter) as it's configuration is more simple and it acts much faster, just provide `<id>` as the left boundary and `</id>` as the right boundary and JMeter will extract everything between the boundaries:

[image]

And last but not the least, [using regular expressions for parsing HTML or XML is not the best idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2897748), you might want to use [CSS Selector Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS_Selector_Extractor) or [XPath Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor) instead, however we need to see the full response in order to be able to come up with the best solution

Comment: How can I add multiple tag values in single regular expression? For an example if the response have ID and ClientNo tags?